# If $(X_n)$ is a Markov chain and $h$ is harmonic then $(h(X_n))$ is a martingale

Tags: probability-theory, markov-chains, conditional-expectation

Im working on the following problem:

$(X_{n})_{n\ge0}$ is a markov chain with state space $S$ and transition matrix $P$, now for a harmonic function $h(i)=\sum_{j}p_{ij}h(j)$ where $p_{ij}$ are the entries of the transition matrix, i want to calculate:

$\Bbb E(h(X_{n+1})|\mathcal A_{n})$ where the sigma algebra $\mathcal A_{n}$ is generated by $X_{0},...X_{n}$.

I just have no idea how to approach this problem, so I dont have any mentionable results to show. I would really appreciate it if somebody could post a solution to the problem.

Comment: First step: Can you show that $\Bbb E(h(X_{n+1})\mid\mathcal A_{n})=\Bbb E(h(X_{n+1})\mid X_{n})$?

Comment: My first problem is that I don't really know how it this expection value define, I know that if the X0,...Xn are a partition then I can use a formula for $\Bbb E(X|\mathcal A_{n})$

Comment: $\Bbb E(X|\mathcal A_{n}) = \sum_{i} \Bbb E(X|A_{i}) * \Bbb 1_{A_{i}}$ where the $A_{i}$ are the sets of the partition